# NameError: global name "foo" is not defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I know this was asked a million times but I still dont get why its happening. Its my first project in python. I only really used C++ before.

There are 3 python files in total: fooA, fooB and fooC. fooC doesnt matter but the others look like this:

**fooB:**

```
from fooC import bla

class fooB:
    def __init__(self):
    a = bla()
    ...
```

**fooA:**

```
import fooB

def main():
    foo1 = fooB()
    ...
```

and I get the Error

> NameError: global name "foo" is not defined

Can someone help me out?

Comment: There is no `foo()` in your code. If you are interested in using `fooB` instead, you need to call it as `fooB.fooB()` *i.e. (<imported_module>.<class>)*

Comment: Well what is `foo()` supposed to be? It isn't defined in the code you have shown

Comment: always in question show full error message (Traceback) - there are other usefull inforamtion - ie. which line makes problem. You don't use `foo` in example code so problem has to be in other part.

Comment: Your exception doesn't match the code you've shown. Please give the full traceback of the exception you're actually getting with the code you've showing us.

Answer (score 0):

You actually run

```
import fooB
fooB()
```

Where fooB is a module. You need to run `fooB.fooB()` or use `from fooB import fooB` (which might be a bit confusing later, as you always need to ask yourself, is this now the module or the function).